# Unable to understand the correct output of my C program

Tags: c, output

My C code is :

```
void main()
{
int a=5,b=6,c=11;
clrscr();
printf("%d %d %d");
getch();
}
```

When i compiled it , it is giving Compile time error but the answer to this question is : 11 6 5

I'm unable to understand how the output is 11 6 5

Please somebody tell the correct output with proper explanation .

Thanks

Comment: _" answer to this question is... "_ throw away that book in trash

Comment: The reason the "answer" is given as 11 6 5 is that the person who wrote the question is assuming that the values 5, 6, and 11 will still be sitting on the machine's stack when printf is called, and that it will act as though those are the arguments to the function. But there is no guarantee at all that the machine will behave that way when you run the program, and a proper compiler (as you have found) will refuse to compile nonsense like this. The other answerers are right that this is undefined behavior, and whoever wrote that question should go back to school.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Program's behavior is **undefined**. You well get anything.

You are passing no arguments to the `printf` function while it is expecting three `int` type arguments. The statement

```
 printf("%d %d %d",c, b, a);
```

will give you desired output.

```
11 6 5
```

Comment: That quote has nothing to do with the code in question.

Answer (score 2):

its behavior is undefined. if you want to show the values of a, b and c you should have coded as below:

> `printf("%d%d%d",a,b,c);`

now the output is:

```
5 6 11
```

Comment: Exactly , why is d here?

Comment: it was a mistake. sorry. I edited.

Answer (score 1):

The program has undefined behaviour, since the `printf` format string requires that you pass three additional `int` arguments, which you aren't doing. Anything could happen. Printing certain output is one form of "anything".